# Make VS code stop adding and inserting characters

Tags: ide, text-editor, visual-studio-code

VS code likes thinking for me, which is the number 1 sin a text editor can 
do. To "help" it will auto type [] and {}, when deleting it will also delete [] instead of just ]. When typing HTML it also tries to auto add `</div>` at the wrong time...

99% of the time when it adds a character I didn't add myself it creates issues. How can I turn that feature off? i.e if I didn't explicitly press a key to modify a character, VS code has no business touching that character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the Settings menu (`Ctrl ,` on Windows or File -> Preferences -> Settings).

Select Text Editor.

You can selectively disable `Auto Closing Brackets`, `Auto Closing Quotes`, and other editor options.

Comment: Thank you, auto insert and auto-complete wasted so much time. Every other answer to this question started with "Click on Tools". I thought the nightmare would never end.